# How to mock Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Range.Tables with Moq?

Tags: c#, vsto, interop, office-interop

I have been trying to mock it but get the null error when I tries to loop through tables in the range.

This is what I have tried so far.

```
        var contentControlMock = new Mock<ContentControl>();        
        contentControlMock.SetupAllProperties();

           
    contentControlMock.SetupProperty(m => m.LockContents); 
    contentControlMock.SetupProperty(m => m.LockContentControl);

        var tableMock = new Mock<Tables>(); 
         
        Mock.Get(contentControlMock.Object)
            .Setup(f => f.Range.Tables)
            .Returns(tableMock.Object);


        var cell = Mock.Of<Cell>();
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.Height).Returns(25);
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.ColumnIndex).Returns(1);
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.BottomPadding).Returns(1);
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.RightPadding).Returns(1);
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.LeftPadding).Returns(1);
        Mock.Get(cell).Setup(p => p.TopPadding).Returns(1);

        var range = Mock.Of<Range>();
        var cells = Mock.Of<Cells>();

      //  four rows, each 25 pt high, 100 pt total
        var cellsArray = new[] { cell, cell, cell, cell };

        Mock.Get(cells).Setup(p => p.GetEnumerator()).Returns(cellsArray.GetEnumerator);

        Mock.Get(range).Setup(p => p.Cells).Returns(cells);

        var table = Mock.Of<Table>();
        Mock.Get(table).Setup(p => p.Range).Returns(range);

        contentControlMock.Setup(m => m.Range).Returns(range);

        //Since, I couldn't add 'table' to Range.Tables I am only adding the first instance. 
        contentControlMock.Setup(m => m.Range.Tables[0]).Returns(table);
```

I also tried the simpler Mock for table.

i.e.

```
var tables = Mock.Of<Tables>(); 
contentControlMock.Setup(m => m.Range.Tables).Returns(tables);
```

Still gets the error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ns4Dq.png)

Comment: Make the Mock strict and see what call is the first that throws a MockException then you know what setup is missing or wrong. (I mean ALL mocks used here).